# minimax with Iterative Deepening search and alpha-beta pruning stopping time of 5 secconds

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

I have to made a kalaha AI which is using alpha beta pruning with Iterative deepening and a time limit of 5 secconds....the alpha beta pruning function works fine and win all the time but the alpha beta pruning with iterative deepening does not work fine...
when it is going to finish, the depthCount is going really deep but shouldn't(like 15000).... I added an image at the end to show this problem

Can sonmeone help me with that?

```
public int minimaxIDAlphaBeta(GameState currentBoard, int maxPlayer, boolean isMax, boolean isMin, int alpha, int beta) {
    int bestMove = 0;
    int depthCount = 1;
    int value = 0;
    Integer maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    start_time = 0;
    time_exceeded = false;
    elapsed_time = 0;

    if (!currentBoard.gameEnded()) {
        start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while (!time_exceeded) {
            elapsed_time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time;
//                GameState newBoard = currentBoard.clone();

            if (elapsed_time > timeLimit) {
                //System.out.println("time out: " + elapsedTime / 1000F + ", and depth count: " + depthCount);
                time_exceeded = true;
                break;
            } else {
//                    if (newBoard.gameEnded()) {
//                        return bestMove;
//                    }

                for (int i = 2; i <= 25 ; i++) //for (int i = 1; elapsed_time < timeLimit ; i++)
                {
                    value = MinimaxIterativeDeepeningAlphaBeta(currentBoard, 1, maxPlayer, isMax, isMin, i, alpha, beta, start_time, time_exceeded);
                    if (value > maxValue) {
                        bestMove = value;
                    }
                    if (elapsed_time >= timeLimit) {
                        System.out.println("depth count: " + i);
                        System.out.println("best move: " + bestMove + ", elapsed time: " + elapsed_time / 1000F);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return bestMove;
}

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
public int MinimaxIterativeDeepeningAlphaBeta(GameState currentBoard, int currentDepth, int maxPlayer, boolean isMax, boolean isMin, int maxDepth, int alpha, int beta,long start_time,boolean exceeded_time) {
    int depth = maxDepth;
    int value = 0;
    Integer maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    Integer minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int bestMove = 0;

    //get elapsed time in milliseconds
    elapsed_time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time;

    //if elapsed time is larger than maximum time limit, then stop searching
    if (elapsed_time > timeLimit) {
        time_exceeded = true;
    }

    //if time is not exceeded 5 sec
    if (!time_exceeded) {

        //if the game is ended or we hit a terminal node, return the maxPlayer score
        if (currentBoard.gameEnded() || currentDepth == depth || time_exceeded == true) {
            if (maxPlayer == 1) {
                return currentBoard.getScore(1) - currentBoard.getScore(2);
            } else {
                return currentBoard.getScore(2) - currentBoard.getScore(1);
            }
        }

        //check to see if it's max turn
        if (isMax) {
            for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {

                //check to see if move is possible or not
                if (currentBoard.moveIsPossible(i)) {

                    //copy the current board in each iteration
                    GameState newBoard = currentBoard.clone();
                    newBoard.makeMove(i);

                    //check to see if the next player is max again or not...if it's next turn is max again set isMax true and isMin false...
                    if (newBoard.getNextPlayer() == maxPlayer) {
                        isMax = true;
                        isMin = false;
                    } else {
                        isMax = false;
                        isMin = true;
                    }

                    if (isMax) {
                        //if it's max turn it will excute this recursive function 
                        value = MinimaxIterativeDeepeningAlphaBeta(newBoard, currentDepth + 1, maxPlayer, isMax, isMin, maxDepth, alpha, beta,start_time,exceeded_time);
                    } else {
                        //if it's min turn it will excute this recursive function
                        value = MinimaxIterativeDeepeningAlphaBeta(newBoard, currentDepth + 1, maxPlayer, isMax, isMin, maxDepth, alpha, beta,start_time,exceeded_time);
                    }

                    //if the value is greater than the max value, it will store the value in max value and the i as the best move
                    if (value > maxValue) {
                        maxValue = value;
                        bestMove = i;
                    }

                    //if maximum value is larger than alpha value, then store maximum value as alpha value
                    if (maxValue > alpha) {
                        alpha = maxValue;
                    }

                    //if the alpha value is larger than beta value, then stop the iteration
                    if (beta <= alpha) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            //as long as the depth is greater than 1 we want to calculate the best value and return, but when the current depth is 1 we want to return the best move instead of best value
            if (currentDepth != 1) {
                bestMove = maxValue;
            }
        } else {    //if it is min turn it will go through the else 
            for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
                if (currentBoard.moveIsPossible(i)) {

                    //copy the current board in each iteration
                    GameState newBoard = currentBoard.clone();
                    newBoard.makeMove(i);

                    //check to see if the next player is min again or not...if it's next turn is min again set isMin true and isMax false...
                    if (newBoard.getNextPlayer() != maxPlayer) {
                        isMax = false;
                        isMin = true;
                    } else {
                        isMax = true;
                        isMin = false;
                    }

                    if (isMin) {
                        //if it's min turn it will excute this recursive function
                        value = MinimaxIterativeDeepeningAlphaBeta(newBoard, currentDepth + 1, maxPlayer, isMax, isMin, maxDepth, alpha, beta,start_time,exceeded_time);
                    } else {
                        //if it's max turn it will excute this recursive function
                        value = MinimaxIterativeDeepeningAlphaBeta(newBoard, currentDepth + 1, maxPlayer, isMax, isMin, maxDepth, alpha, beta,start_time,exceeded_time);
                    }

                    //if the value is less than the min value, it will store the value in min value and the i as the best move
                    if (value < minValue) {
                        minValue = value;
                        bestMove = i;
                    }

                    //if minimum value is smaller than beta value, then store minimum value as beta value
                    if (minValue < beta) {
                        beta = minValue;
                    }

                    //if the beta value is smaller than alpha value, then stop the iteration
                    if (beta <= alpha) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            //as long as the depth is greater than 1 we want to calculate the best value and return, but when the current depth is 1 we want to return the best move instead of best value
            if (currentDepth != 1) {
                bestMove = minValue;
            }
        }
    }


    //when the current depth equals to 1 it will return the best move 
    return bestMove;
}
```

[image: depthCount of the last 3 moves]

[image]

Comment: I noticed that you called MinimaxIterativeDeepeningAlphaBeta with the same arguments in an if and an else branch (twice). This is not the bug, but you could simplify your code.

Comment: You checked if value > maxValue in the first function, but on depth 1 you return the best move instead of a node value from the second function, so this check does not make much sense to me.

Comment: @Cepheus beacause it's minimax tree and im using recursive function...so after it hits a terminal node it should returns value when the depth is greater than 1 and when it is 1 we return the move instead of the value...I hope I made my point

Comment: Yes, but the condition (value > maxValue) in the first function is always true, because a move (number between 1 and 7) is always greater than maxValue (= Integer.MIN_VALUE).

Comment: @Cepheus when we get to the first function we have to be sure that the maxValue get a value so I had to give it a really low value to make it true and I don't think that is the problem ....I checked some other code and in those code it was something like this but I'm not sure though...

Comment: @Cepheus I can make you sure that the GameState class does not have bug....because all the parts where there and I had to make the AI part for it...so it works fine....and I check the code around 10 times with alpha beta pruning without iterative deepening and in all of those AI wins...I guess that something wrong with my minimaxIDAlphaBeta() function but I can't find it out...

Comment: currentBoard.getWinner() == -1 only if no one has won?

Comment: @Cepheus yes and 0 if it draws..... 1 and 2 if one of them wins(e.g. max wins returns 1 and min wins returns 2)

Comment: I think currentBoard.getWinner() in the loop is always -1, so you always increase the depth and reach the timelimit eventually. The reason is that currentBoard is the original board and inside the second function you make your moves on a clone of the board. So the winner of the original board is never changed.

Comment: @Cepheus so should I clone the cuurentBoard in the first function and use it instead of cloning in the first function?

Comment: No, because you have to undo your moves...

Comment: @Cepheus so what do you suggest?

Comment: 1. You should always return the value and store the best move in a member variable instead. 2. You could exit the ID loop in the first function as soon as your second function returns a terminal value, i.e. not min_value or max_value. Because then alphabeta reached a terminal node and you would not reach a better terminal node at a greater depth if I'm right.

Comment: @Cepheus thanks for the tips

Comment: @Cepheus ofcourse man...I will

Comment: I think you cannot just abort the search if you found a terminal state because you might find a better move with a greater search depth limit. Anyway, I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

Consider the iterative deepening loop in the first function `minimaxIDAlphaBeta`:

```
if (currentBoard.getWinner() > -1) {
    return bestMove;
}

for (int i = 1; currentBoard.getWinner() == -1; i++) //for (int i = 1; elapsed_time < timeLimit ; i++)
{
    value = MinimaxIterativeDeepeningAlphaBeta(currentBoard, 1, maxPlayer, isMax, isMin, i, alpha, beta, start_time, time_exceeded);
    // code omitted for clarity
    if (elapsed_time >= 4999) {
        // code omitted for clarity
        break;
    }
}
```

And consider the alpha beta search of the second function:

```
public int MinimaxIterativeDeepeningAlphaBeta(GameState currentBoard, int currentDepth, int maxPlayer, boolean isMax, boolean isMin, int maxDepth, int alpha, int beta,long start_time,boolean exceeded_time) {
    // code omitted for clarity

            for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {

                //check to see if move is possible or not
                if (currentBoard.moveIsPossible(i)) {

                    //copy the current board in each iteration
                    GameState newBoard = currentBoard.clone();
                    newBoard.makeMove(i);

                    // code omitted for clarity
                }
            }

    // code omitted for clarity
}
```

Each move is made on a clone of the game state, which is correct since a move must be reversed before exiting the alpha-beta function.
However, in the iterative deepening loop only the original game state is asked if the game is over (and the game is *never* over for the original game state!).
So the loop will always run until the time limit is reached.

### Possible Solution

Usually two abort criteria are used for Iterative Deepening:

- Maximal depth reached (this is missing) and
- Timeout

It would be wrong to terminate the search as soon as you found a terminal state because you might find a better move with a greater search depth limit.

Comment: @Cephereus I changed the currentBoard.getwinner() == -1 to elapsed_time <= timeLimit and still not working

Comment: I think you *also* need to abort if you exceed a certain max depth, e.g. 100. Because what happens, I believe, is the following: Your alpha-beta search returns very quickly because your search tree is very shallow at the end of the game. Let's say your search tree has only height 5. Then the ID loop makes a lot of iterations, increasing the max search depth, although you already have exhaustively searched your entire search tree.

Comment: @amireghbalian You could confirm my assumption by logging the maximum reached search depth of your second function. It should be much less than the variable i in the ID loop.

Comment: I changed my first function and set a depth limit of 25 but still not working....I edited the code....You can check it out

Comment: @amireghbalian It should work IMO. Your depth limit is 25, so you search at most to depth 25. Or what makes you think that it does not work? What does your output say?

Comment: I think 1 problem is because of the get score function in alpha beta...when the time is reached and try to return best values it never get in the if statement the get the score so i put it out of the if(!time_exceeded) and right now im testing and it worked fine until now but the high depth problem still exist

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please post the output of your program in your question (and/or update your screenshots), so that we see that the max. search depth is still not respected? @amireghbalian

Comment: right now Im testing my app and it's working fine aftar that fix...if I face that problem again I will update the screenshots but if not im gonna choose your solution as the correct one...

Comment: @amireghbalian Could you please accept my answer if the problem is solved?

Comment: actually my problem stay still....it still has the deep depth problem....sometimes it goes too deep something like 10000

Comment: @amireghbalian That's strange. If you update your screenshot (and your code if it changed), I will have a look at it.